# Not able to access Publisher URL after SSL certificate renewal

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We have renewed our self-signed internal certificate in WSO2 API Manager 3.2 as below and after that we are not able to access the Publisher and Dev Portal URLs. However we are able to access the Carbon URL.

Here are the steps followed.

```
keytool -genkey -alias wso2mcm -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore wso2mcm.jks -dname "CN=ad.local.com, OU=Home,O=Home,L=SL,S=WS,C=LK" --storepass wso2carbon -keypass wso2carbon -validity 365
keytool -export -alias wso2mcm -keystore wso2mcm.jks -file wso2mcm.pem
keytool -delete -alias wso2mcm -keystore client-truststore.jks
keytool -import -alias wso2mcm -file wso2mcm.pem -keystore client-truststore.jks -storepass wso2carbon
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore wso2mcm.jks -destkeystore wso2mcm.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12
```

**Entries from deployment.toml file are as below**

```
[keystore.tls]
file_name =  "wso2mcm.jks"
type =  "JKS"
password =  "wso2carbon"
alias =  "wso2mcm"
key_password =  "wso2carbon"

[keystore.primary]
file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
type =  "JKS"
password =  "wso2carbon"
alias =  "wso2carbon"
key_password =  "wso2carbon"

[keystore.internal]
file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
type =  "JKS"
password =  "wso2carbon"
alias =  "wso2carbon"
key_password =  "wso2carbon"
```

Is there any additional steps to be followed? Please help us to resolve this issue

Please find below the error screenshot and log entries from carbon log file

[image]

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-12-16 13:10:11,367] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service} - Error occurred while issuing the access token for Client ID : P_3DbvpsLEMzJJa89HsBFEjEJaUa, User ID null, Scope : [] and Grant Type : authorization_code java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1011)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1006)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util.getPrivateKey(OAuth2Util.java:2370)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util.signJWTWithRSA(OAuth2Util.java:2327)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util.signJWT(OAuth2Util.java:2287)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.openidconnect.DefaultIDTokenBuilder.getIDToken(DefaultIDTokenBuilder.java:295)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.openidconnect.DefaultIDTokenBuilder.buildIDToken(DefaultIDTokenBuilder.java:204)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.AccessTokenIssuer.issue(AccessTokenIssuer.java:338)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service.issueAccessToken(OAuth2Service.java:254)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.token.OAuth2TokenEndpoint.issueAccessToken(OAuth2TokenEndpoint.java:318)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.token.OAuth2TokenEndpoint.issueAccessToken(OAuth2TokenEndpoint.java:94)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:193)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:103)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:216)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:220)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.filter.AuthorizationHeaderFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationHeaderFilter.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:86)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:101)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the same commands you mentioned and was able to successfully update the certificate.

The error you received occurs when the primary keystore password and key password are different. During the certificate update, you might have changed the key password of wso2carbon.jks.
Can you try the below command and change it back to wso2carbon?

```
keytool -keypasswd -keystore wso2carbon.jks -alias wso2carbon
```

This will ask for the existing password for keystore and the private key. If wso2carbon does not match, that means password has been changed and either you have to use the correct password or create a new keystore and use it as primary and internal keystore. For your testing purposes, you can even replace the Keystore from another APIM distribution.

**Update**

Since you have changed the client secret of the publisher SP app, you either have to update the SP app clientSecret in the `AM_SYSTEM_APPS` table or create a new SP for the publisher login.

You can create a new SP with,

1. Delete the existing SP app with the name `apim_publisher`
2. Delete the apim_publisher entry from `AM_SYSTEM_APPS` table.
3. Login again from the publisher portal.

Login again will create a new SP.

Comment: Hi Lakshitha, we have executed the command keytool -keypasswd -keystore wso2carbon.jks -alias wso2carbon with the existing password (wso2carbon) and the command is successfully executed. We have also restored the keystores from our another running instance and now we could able to access the /carbon and /devportal urls. However /publisher page is still throwing same error. We have also tried regenerating the secrets for apim_publisher from carbon service provider list and also regenerated the oauth tokens from devportal

Comment: is this a distributed setup? or an all in one setup?

Comment: It is a two node setup. Each node has Carbon, Publisher and DevPortal running

Comment: Have you used the same Keystore and truststore for both nodes?

Comment: It was a same certificate on both the nodes. We generated from one node and copied into the other node.

Comment: Hi Lakshitha - The key issue is not appearing now after replacing the correct keystore. However we are still not able access the publisher URL but the /devportal is working fine. I guess the issue is with oauth token generation. We tried regenerating secret for "apim_publisher" service provider.

Comment: That's because we store the clientID, secret of the SP app in the ```AM_SYSTEM_APPS``` table. Either you need to update the new secret in the table, or delete the sp app from carbon console, delete the `apim_publisher` app from the db table and login back to the publisher. This will create a new SP app for publisher.

Comment: Hi Lakshitha, it worked. We executed the query "update public.am_system_apps set consumer_secret='9isrrVd0RQrzDY7Yj8qafiMkrZ8a' where name='apim_publisher'" and the issue got resolved. Why the "am_system_apps" table was not automatically updated with regenerated client-key/secret?

Comment: These two are discontinued operations and it is not something done frequently or recommended to do so. In case you change it, you have to update the configurations. I will update my above answer to include these details.